# Reasons for setting up standalone solr server when using Sunspot in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, solr, sunspot

I am trying to figure out why we shouldn't use sunspot gem by itself in production environment?

Most people recommend setting up a standalone **solr** service such as **jetty+solr** or **tomcat+solr**.

Can anybody explain what are the cons of running as an embedded service?

Answer (score 0):

Sunspot is perfectly usable in production. You have to set up your own Solr server, though, which I think is what you're talking about. For that, there's an [already answered StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937314/setup-sunspot-solr-with-rails-in-production-environment) that I think will help you get started.

Comment: I mean why we can't go with embeded **solr** in production

Comment: @Vladimir I think this [wiki page](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/EmbeddedSolr) should give you a reasonable answer.

Answer (score 0):

This link has some info: http://outoftime.github.com/pivotal-sunspot-presentation.html It also says it should be on its own machine.