# Sunspor Solr in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I saw this question [Setup sunspot solr with rails in production environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937314/setup-sunspot-solr-with-rails-in-production-environment/4939936#4939936).

But I see my output:

```
bundle exec sunspot-solr start

...sunspot_solr is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.
```

I have sunspot_solr under development group, and I suppose I should not change that.

## Bundler output

```
Using rsolr (1.0.8) 
...
Using sunspot (1.3.3) 
Using sunspot_rails (1.3.3)
```

## Rake output

```
rake sunspot:solr:start RAILS_ENV=production

Note: This task has been moved to the sunspot_solr gem. To install, start and
stop a local Solr instance, please add sunspot_solr to your Gemfile:

group :development do
  gem 'sunspot_solr'
end
```

Any advice, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try putting the gems outside the development group?

I have the following gems outside the development group:

```
gem 'sunspot_rails'
gem 'sunspot_solr'
```

Comment: Thanks, I get biased with another questions and answers.