# Why not sunspot_solr in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot-solr

I am using the following gems in my project

```
gem 'sunspot_rails'

group :development do
  gem 'sunspot_solr'
end
```

I am trying to figure out why we shouldn't use sunspot gem by itself in production environment?

Most people recommend setting up a standalone solr service such as **jetty+solr** or **tomcat+solr**

There are several links that explain solr in production:

[Setup sunspot solr with rails in production environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937314/setup-sunspot-solr-with-rails-in-production-environment?lq=1)

http://outoftime.github.io/pivotal-sunspot-presentation.html

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/EmbeddedSolr

But they dont say **why?**

I tried putting all production data and creating indexes as i would need in production and faced no problem. 
Is there anyone who has used the sunspot_solr in production and faced problems?